# Back button "And" edit button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UINavigationController that pushes a UiviewController to it's stack. This UIViewController has a UITableView.

I have an edit table button in the top left of the navigation bar which means I've lost my back button.

How can I have both?

Comment: You could place the edit button on the right. Then there is no issue.

Comment: place edit as right bar button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set 2 buttons as left bar button item, then check this

[Multiple UIBarButtonItems in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100840/multiple-uibarbuttonitems-in-uinavigationbar)

In this link there are 2 buttons set as right bar button item, You can set as leftbarbuttonitem inplace of rightbarbuttonitem.