# How can I add multiple UIBarButtonItem's to a UINavigationBar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add many `UIBarButtonItem`'s to a `UINavigationbar`, not just right and left buttons:

```
logoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"A Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logoButtonAClicked:)];

logoButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"B Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logoButtonBClicked:)];

logoButto3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"C Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logoButtonCClicked:)];

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

self.title = @"Title";

NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:logoButtonA, logoButtonB, logoButtonC, nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.items = items;
```

I get a `SIGBRT` on `self.navigationController.navigationBar.items = items;`

How can I add multiple `UIBarButtonItem`s to a `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple UIBarButtonItems in UINavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100840/multiple-uibarbuttonitems-in-uinavigationbar)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add `UIBarButtonItem` instance to a `UINavigationItem`, not to a `UINavigationBar`. So you can do this as:

```
NSArray *buttonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:logoButton, logoButton2, logoButton3, nil];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = buttonArray;
```

If you want your buttons on the right, use `rightBarButtonItems`.

Comment: Is there a way to add left bar buttons without making the back button disappear?

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = items;
```

Answer (score -1):

use addSubView in navigationbar.

Comment: Not a great idea ... those buttons don't look or behave like standard `UIBarButtonItem` instances and, additionally, `UIBarButtonItem` isn't a subclass of `UIView`, so you can't call [navigationBar addSubview:logoButton]`.

Comment: -1: From `UINavigationBar` docs: `When you use a navigation bar as a standalone object, you are responsible for providing its contents. Unlike other types of views, you do not add subviews to a navigation bar directly. Instead, you use a navigation item (an instance of the UINavigationItem class) to specify what buttons or custom views you want displayed.`