# Add button (UIButtonBarItem) is not visible in navigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios7

Actually I added two button (UIButtonBarItem) and assigned it to to NavigationItem's rightbarbuttonitem but only edit button is visible and add button is not visible but when we click on it it gets invoked ?
chk it out my code http://pastebin.com/Ew4zPEUz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code in `ViewDidload` method

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,60,30);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneBackButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barButtonItem;
```

Comment: He wanted more than one button.

Comment: well .. thanx for commenting @indianarmy but in my case i was trying to insert UIBarButtonItem and it was not visible ..but now solved it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867259/how-can-i-add-multiple-uibarbuttonitems-to-a-uinavigationbar                  it will be help[full

Answer (score 0):

finally solved this problem .

just removed below line

```
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor]
```

and its works :)